# Data localization in mapping in ASP.NET Zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

I'd like to know if there is a way to use localization based on data in the mapping of DTOs, something like:

```
public class EntityX : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityXTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class EntityXTranslation
{
    public virtual int EntityXId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityXDto : FullAuditedEntityDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
configuration.CreateMap<EntityX, EntityXDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Name, options =>
    {
        var languageId = 1; //TODO: get current language
        options.MapFrom(uom => uom.Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.LanguageId == languageId).Name);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a couple of hours investigation I got a nice way to do it:

```
configuration.CreateMap<UnitOfMeasure, UnitOfMeasureListItem>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Name, options =>
                       MapFromTranslated<EntityX, 
                                         EntityXTranslation, 
                                         EntityXDto, 
                                         string>(options, t => t.Name));

void MapFromTranslated<TSource, TTranslation, TDestination, TMember>
                (IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> options, 
                 Expression<Func<TTranslation, TMember>> member)
    where TSource : IHaveTranslations<TTranslation>
    where TTranslation : TranslationEntity
{
    options.MapFrom(uom => MapTranslation(uom, member));
    options.MapAtRuntime();
}

TMember MapTranslation<TSource, TTranslation, TMember>
                (TSource entity, Expression<Func<TTranslation, TMember>> member)
    where TSource : IHaveTranslations<TTranslation>
    where TTranslation : TranslationEntity
{
    var languageName = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name.Split('-').FirstOrDefault();
    var translation = entity.Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Language.Name.Contains(languageName)) ?? entity.Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.LanguageId == 1);
    var translationParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTranslation), "t");
    var targetProperty = Expression.Property(translationParameter, ((MemberExpression)member.Body).Member.Name);
    var action = Expression.Lambda<Func<TTranslation, TMember>>(targetProperty, translationParameter);
    return action.Compile().Invoke(translation);
}
```