# Automapper ProjectTo does not map multi lingual entity

Tags: automapper, aspnetboilerplate

The ABP multi lingual mapping was not being called by AutoMapper ProjectTo. If it work, it suppose to map the translation entity to DTO's name property. It works with my old code without using ProjectTo. Please refer to the sample code below:

**NOTE** : I am using ABP version 4.8.1

**NOTE** : I have included the Translation DTO in ProductDTO to force auto mapper's projectTo to eagerly load Translation data when generating the IQueryable.

**ProductAppService.cs**

```
public async Task<ICollection<ProductListDto>> GetAll()
{
     return await repository.GetAll().ProjectTo<ProductListDto>().ToListAsync();
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product : Entity, IMultiLingualEntity<ProductTranslation>
{
    public ICollection<ProductTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductTranslation.cs**

```
public class ProductTranslation : Entity, IEntityTranslation<Product>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductDto.cs**

```
public class ProductListDto
{
    // Mapped from ProductTranslation.Name
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Purposely include the translations dto here to force automapper to eagerly load the translation 
    // data from DB
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<ProductTranslationDto> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

**Module.cs**

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(cfg =>
    {
        MultiLingualMapContext context = new MultiLingualMapContext(IocManager.Resolve<ISettingManager>());
        cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();
        cfg.AddCollectionMappers();

        CustomDtoMapper.CreateMappings(cfg);
    });
}
```

**CustomDtoMapper.cs**

```
cfg.CreateMultiLingualMap<Product, ProductTranslation, ProductListDto>(context);
```

Comment: Appreciate if anyone can pin point how to make it works? I mean customisation of the existing asp.net boilerplate code. I believe ProjectTo is the way to go when mapping EF core entities to DTOs because it improve performance and productivity.

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem? I have exactly the same problem with ProjectTo and multilingual Abp...

Answer (score 0):

could you check those links, it appears to be an old issue based on github

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3356

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/e0ded5d8702f389aa1f5947d3446f16aec845287/test/Abp.ZeroCore.Tests/Zero/MultiLingual/MultiLingual_Entity_Tests.cs

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/e0ded5d870/test/Abp.ZeroCore.SampleApp/Application/Shop/ProductAppService.cs#L48

And Here is an StackOverFlow Question about it.

[Data localization in mapping in ASP.NET Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910164/data-localization-in-mapping-in-asp-net-zero/48931939#48931939)

Please let me know if one of them works for you.

Comment: actually I was able to map asp.net boilerplate multi lingual entities mapping works between IMultiLingualEntity and  IEntityTranslation interface. What i want to achieve is to use Automapper ProjectTo method to map ef core query result to DTO with multi lingual mapping